# Using Rails built-in validator to validate hash with dynamic options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models, `CharacterSheet` and `Sheet`, both of which have the column `properties`. `Sheet`'s `properties` column is used to store key-value pairs of property names and their validation (which are in idiomatically correct Ruby `validates` syntax).

```
Sheet.create!(name: 'A Test Sheet',
              properties: {
                prop1: { numericality: { only_integer: true }, length: { maximum: 3 } },
                prop2: { numericality: { only_integer: true }, length: { minimum: 1 } },
                prop3: { numericality: { only_integer: true } }
              })
```

`CharacterSheet` stores key-value pairs of property names and their actual values, validated by the appropriate `Sheet` key-value pair.

```
CharacterSheet.create(sheet_id: 1,
                      name: 'A Test CharacterSheet',
                      properties: {
                        prop1: 123,
                        prop2: 234,
                        prop3: 345
                    })
```

Ideally, I want to use the validation requirements stored in `Sheet.properties` to use Rails' built-in validation methods, so I don't have to rewrite all of that validation myself. However, I can't find an appropriate method to hook into. `self.validates` doesn't seem to serve my purposes since it seems like (from what I could tell) it requires a valid column name, which it then uses to pull the value, instead of allowing a value to be passed in directly.

Comment: Why does `self.validates` not seem to serve your purposes?

Comment: @alexanderbird `self.validates` (from what I could tell) looks like it requires a column name to reference the value, when what I need is to pass in a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

So the first problem I see is that you'll need also to convert what it means, numericality and how to fetch that property, and only_integer and what does that mean. 
I would advise you to use something like

```
prop_name: { type_of_validation: 'regexp', validator: 'Regex-representation' }
prop_name2: { type_of_validation: 'type', validator: 'Hash' }
```

the regex representation will need to be double-escaped.

because then you can do

```
 loaded_sheet = Sheet.find(csheet.sheet_id).properties.as_json.with_indifferent_access
    csheet.properties.as_json.with_indifferent_access.each do |k,v|
      if loaded_sheet[k.to_sym][:type_of_validation] == 'regexp'
        regex = Regexp.new loaded_sheet[k.to_sym][:validator]
        return false unless v =~ regex
      elsif loaded_sheet[k.to_sym[:type_of_validation] == 'type'
        return false unless v.is_a?(loaded_sheet[k.to_sym][:validator].constantize)
      end
    end
```

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is validation *without* having to re-define what numericality, etc. mean and instead use Rails' built-in validator and definitions.

Comment: @user2706191 - ah I didn't even realise those were default validators for rails. Can't help you. Probably if on the sheet each propN is an array instead of an hash you could splat them into a validates not sure how you would make the value available though. Unless you created a concept model, with no DB record underlying, so you could do Placeholdermodel.new(splat your attr hash) and then called validate on that construction. You would have a validate_with :method on your "real" model, that would create the placeholder, parse the sheet validations, and call the validations on it

Comment: Prolly there's a much better way, like hacking your own validator that just copies the original validates method but accepts values and making it available to this model and calling validates_with that validator